# Simulate Standard Windows Popup message Beep sound

Tags: nsis

I would like to simulate the standard windows popup message Beep sound in order to have each popup message in my script with the same sound effect.

In my script I use the default clause MUI_ABORTWARNING so, when the relative popup message is displayed, the standard windows popup message Beep is played.

For my purpose, I tryed to use the following API call but the sound effect is very different

```
System::Call "kernel32::Beep(i, i) b (${BEEP_FREQ_HZ}, ${BEEP_DURATION_MSEC})"
```

How can I do to accomplish the task?

Many thanks in advance to everyone that can help me on this.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kernel32::Beep` tries to use the little hardware speaker in your machine, if not available it uses the default system sound.

Use [`MessageBeep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebeep) to generate a standard sound:

```
!define /IfNDef MB_ICONWARNING 0x00000030 ; You might want MB_ICONINFORMATION or MB_ICONSTOP instead
System::Call 'USER32::MessageBeep(i ${MB_ICONWARNING})'
```

If you are actually calling `MessageBox` in your NSIS code then you don't need to call `MessageBeep`, `MessageBeep` will be called for you if you use one of the `MB_ICON*` flags.

Comment: Tks... answer cristal clear. I used MB_ICONEXCLAMATION flag and it worked without using API call back function